# How much time does it take for an android app to appear on google play store after submitting in google play for the first time?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have developed an app and I wish to release it to internal track. How long does it take for Google to review and publish the app to internal track?

Also, is there any way to move it to production track once it has been approved?

Comment: Its may take 4 hours to 4 weeks nowadays as per policy and usage of your app.

Comment: it may take upto from 1 hrs to 12 hrs max

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When you publish an android APK or Bundle for the first time, it may take a minimum 3 days or less depends on a traffic of a queue. After you upload
> your app for the second time, it may take 1 to 2 hours to go live on play
> store.

below are more links to help you.

- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en
- https://medium.com/@pawardeepakv/google-play-console-internal-test-c6e4ea369ed8
- https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle
- https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-to-publish-a-mobile-app-on-Google-play

I hope this helps you.

Comment: if the app got approved and how long will it take to move from alpha track to production track?

Comment: Hey @AshokReddy happy to help you... it's may take min 2 hrs to 1 day max to Alpha / Beta to production Track

Comment: Hey @InsaneCat In that case can we have timed publishing?

Comment: it may take upto  from 1 hrs to 12 hrs max

Comment: Actually it's 3 days or more. Less is if you're lucky.
Google state that it may [takes up to 7 days or longer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?visit_id=637471973667304462-526426850&rd=1)